# NGUI elements are being shown as black area in iPod4 and iPhone4

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, iphone-4, ngui

I am working on a game in Unity3d and I am facing a bizarre problem. My NGUI elements are turned into a black area when I run the game into iPod4 and iPhone4. However it is working well in iPad, iPod5 and iPhone5.

It seems to me that in iPod NGUI is not able to get the corresponding Atlas. Even the UIlabel are being shown as a black area in NGUI. Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Is there any memory problem on a lower capability device that might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Black sprites in NGUI on mobile platforms are usually caused by your atlas being larger than what is supported by the hardware. It's a simple physical limitation. The hardware simply does not support textures of a larger size.

The iPad and iPad2 (originally, though this changed) are limited to 2k textures. The iPad 2 (now), 3 and 4, as well as the Mini, the iPhone 4S and 5, and the iPod 5 do have 4k texture support.

So that explains the issues you were having. A simple hardware limitation.

Comment: > I still don't know the actual reason why it was happening... Ankush: it's actual reason of this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I got the solution. The problem caused by NGUI Atlas which was of 4096*4096. I have lower the atlas's resolution 2048*2048. Now everything is fine.

Black sprites in NGUI on mobile platforms are usually caused by your atlas being larger than what is supported by the hardware. It's a simple physical limitation

Comment: May be it caused by memory issue .